# How to enable Java Agent debugging in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javaagents

> If you still don’t understand why there are uninstrumented calls or
>   methods, you can also turn on the instrumentation traces, as well as
>   additional checks, by adding respectively the v, d and c arguments to
>   the Java agent (the corresponding AOT instrumentation task options are
>   verbose, debug and check respectively). This will print thoroughly all
>   the steps of Quasar’s instrumentation process, including which methods
>   calls are considered suspendable (or aren’t, and why) and which are
>   actually instrumented (or aren’t, and why).

[Reference](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/)

I have the following line in `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec)
        {
            jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.iterator().next()}"
        }
```

How should I pass arguments to Java Agent? I tried some ways but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add it at the end:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec)
{
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.iterator().next()}=vdc"
}
```